# Analyzing multiple yes/no features of a sample

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multiple-comparisons, discrete-data

What will be the best statistical way to analyze presence/absence of multiple discrete variables for a given sample.

Following is example data which shows 4 variables, each of which can be only Yes or No.

```
case    A   B   C   D
1       yes yes no  no
2       no  no  no  yes
3       yes no  yes no
4       no  no  no  yes
5       no  yes no  no
.....
.....
```

Total number of cases in the data is about 125. I would like to know which combination of these variables is most representative of this population. Is there any name for this kind of problem? There are 16 possible permutations (yyyy, yyyn, yynn ... etc). What statistical test can I apply to determine if frequency of a particular combination is significantly different from other combinations. Also, multiple statistical tests would be needed in this crude approach (16*15 tests). Would multivariate methods be more applicable for this kind of data? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You only have 16 possible combinations of the four variables, so you could view this as *univariate* data representing a sample of one variable with 16 categories.  That's standard--I know you know of many approaches to it, beginning with $\chi^2$ analyses.  Since you ask only about frequencies in each category, the multivariate appearance of these data seems irrelevant.

Comment: Very good points. Simplifies analysis greatly.